# Insert while updating a column with a single value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple need for MySQL. I familiar with how to insert data from one table to another:

```
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, col2 FROM otherTable
```

What I would like to do is something slightly different where I have a new column that I want to populate with a single value for all data being inserted.

```
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3=1984) 
SELECT col1, col2 FROM otherTable
```

I tried the above as well as:

```
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3='1984') 
SELECT col1, col2 FROM otherTable
```

Searching around I wasn't able to find anything on here quickly.

Comment: INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT col1, col2,'1984' FROM otherTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close.

Put it in the select list

```
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT col1, col2,'1984' 
FROM otherTable
```